# Search by location in fanpage

Tags: facebook, google-maps, facebook-page

I want to add the functionality to search for the nearest outlet(same like [this](https://www.facebook.com/bestbuy?sk=locations)). I am having trouble implementing it. Does anyone have an idea how to include searching of outlets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like they are just using the BING maps API filtering only BEST BUYS and then having the users location search the variable in the query... Google maps has one too.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: You mean its just this?http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=localsearch#localsearch